# Syntax for French_CI_AS when dealing with decimals

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, decimal, collation

I've been doing a lot of Google searches trying to find the exact syntax necessary to INSERT or UPDATE a colum with a decimal value using French (Canadian) localization. *I am not a native French speaker, nor do I have any experience with using the French collation.* Using Latin_General_CI_AS the query would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable] (ID, StringField, DecimalField) VALUES (1, 'Some value', 0.5)
```

But when using the French collation, the decimal number looks like `0,5` instead of `0.5` and just a simple translation throw SQL Server into a tizzy.  The INSERT query would look something like this (*although, this doesn't work*):

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable] (ID, StringField, DecimalField) VALUES (1, 'Some value', 0,5)
```

SQL Server thinks `5` is an additional value for a column that wasn't specified.  How can I make this work.  Is there some character that I would wrap the number with to make SQL Server see it as the decimal value?

Comment: The collation is irrelevant here, because it applies to character data only. Where is the 0,5 value coming from and how are you executing your SQL query? The general solution is to assign the value to a parameter, using your front-end application to handle any locale or formatting issues, then execute the SQL with the parameter instead of the literal. However, this depends how you generate and execute your SQL queries and what programming tools or framework you use.

Comment: It's coming from a stored procedure on the database as well.  0.5 doesn't seem to work and after looking to edit the database manually through MSSQLMS, the value was displayed in the column as 0,5

Comment: How is it coming from the stored procedure (in a result set, as an output variable?) and how are you then passing that value to the `INSERT`? If the value is always handled as a `decimal` data type, and if all the processing happens on the server, there is no reason for any error. The formatting only happens when a GUI is involved. It would also be good if you could post exact error messages: a "tizzy" could mean anything :)

Answer (score 0):

Its not about collation, its about decimal separator that is used.

You should use parameters query. If you are using parametrized command, then SQL data providers take care about decimal separators.

```
string sqlcom = @"EXECUTE [dbo].[MyProc]  @x";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sqlcom, MyConnectionX);
com.Parameters.Add("@x", SqlDbType.Decimal);
com.Parameters["@x"].Value = someValue;
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```